# OpenCv with Cuda - (CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version)

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cuda

Whenever I attempt to use the OpenCv GPU library, I get the above error. CUDA outside of OpenCv works fine, however.

A few notes about the computer:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- CUDA version 5.5
- CUDA driver version 319.49
- Work computer, not mine, so it may have had previous versions of CUDA
  installed.

Anyone have this issue before? Or know what might be causing it?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. The driver you have is too old for the runtime library your OpenCV is built against. You probably are going to have to upgrade the drvier